# "Please specify a shipping method."

Tags: shipping, paypal, delivery

Hi there I keep getting "Please specify a shipping method" on my magento website when checkout with paypal express and also having issues with Paypal in general. I would really appreciate help.

Also get emails:

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

http://mywesite.co.uk/index.php/paypal/ipn/

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account.

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to checkout on a site that is only available to your locally, or is this a publicly available site? If you've modified your hosts file to make mywebsite.co.uk point to a locally installed site, that's the issue. PayPal needs to be able to connect to your server.

Comment: Hi here its is live on a domain publicly

Comment: Have you attempted to contact PayPal? Your IPNs are failing for some reason, and you need to fix that ASAP. I would start with this guide on testing and troubleshooting the IPN: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/#id089BD0L50PF

Comment: You should have feedback in your PayPal account regarding the failed IPN messages. On the Magento side you can turn on debugging in the PayPal method configuration. One possible solution: http://www.dhmedia.com.au/article/debugging-paypal-ipn-postback-failures-magento